# Flutter: Grid View force element on bottom

Tags: flutter, gridview, dart, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

I am new to flutter and I am building my first app.
I use Staggered Grid View (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-) which should behave like the normal Grid View.

My settings are:  body: StaggeredGridView.count( crossAxisCount: 4 ...
which means, that I can arrange 4 elements next to each other. Everything is working fine.

But now I want to force one element in the next column and place it in the middle and not next to the other ones. How can I do that?

Thanks for help!

```
   body: StaggeredGridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
    children: <Widget>[
    _buildTile(
        Padding
        (
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Row
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>
            [
             Material
              (
                child: Padding(
                child: Icon(Icons.store, color: Colors.black54, size: 40.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),)
             ),
             Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Text('Test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                  Text('Test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0))
                ],
              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => print('Not set yet'),
      ),
      _buildTile(
        Padding
        (
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Row
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>
            [
             Material
              (
                child: Padding(
                child: Icon(Icons.store, color: Colors.black54, size: 40.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),)
             ),
             Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Text('Test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                  Text('Test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0))
                ],
              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => print('Not set yet'),
      ),
       _buildTile(
        Padding
        (
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Row
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>
            [
             Material
              (
                child: Padding(
                child: Icon(Icons.store, color: Colors.black54, size: 40.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),)
             ),
             Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Text('test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                  Text('test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0))
                ],
              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => print('Not set yet'),
      ),
      _buildTile(
        Padding
        (
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
            children: <Widget>
            [
              Material
              (
                color: Colors.teal,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                child: Center
                (

                   child: Icon(Icons.settings_applications, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),

                )
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
       _buildTile(
        Padding
        (
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column
          (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
            children: <Widget>
            [

              Material
              (
                color: Colors.teal,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                child: Center
                (

                    child: Icon(Icons.settings_applications, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),

                )
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
     //THIS IS THE ELEMENT I WANT TO FORCE TO THE NEXT COLUMN AND CENTER
     _buildTile(QrImage(data: "1234567890", version: QrVersions.auto, size: 200.0,),),
      ], 
    staggeredTiles: [
      StaggeredTile.extent(4, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),
      StaggeredTile.extent(4, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),
      StaggeredTile.extent(4, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),      
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-(8+12)*2)/6),      
    ],
  ),
);
}

Widget _buildTile(Widget child, {Function() onTap}) {
return Material(
  elevation: 14.0,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
  child: InkWell
  (
    // Do onTap() if it isn't null, otherwise do print()
    onTap: onTap != null ? () => onTap() : () { print('${MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top}'); },
    child: child
  )
);
 }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Hi, I added the code. At the bottom you can see the QrCode (build by a plugin) which i want to force to the next column (bottom) and center. 
(The code works, the problem is that I don't know how to position the last element)

Comment: To be able to reproduce your issue we need to have some of the variables you are using, like `kToolbarHeight`.

Comment: kToolbarHeight is implemented in flutter, it just gives the height of the toolbar. For the problem it doesn't matter how big the elements are, if you want you can just set them on a random height like 180.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thank you for clarifying.